# Error en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Tengo una duda sobre postgresql que no me permite avanzar y quizá sea algo sencillo que estoy olvidando u omitiendo.

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE public.p_proyecto
(
    id_proyecto INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL(('p_proyecto_id_proyecto_seq'::text)::regclass),
    id_municipio INTEGER,
    denominacion CHARACTER VARYING(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fase CHARACTER VARYING(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    id_financiamiento INTEGER,
    montofinanciamiento NUMERIC(10,2),
    tiempoejecucion CHARACTER VARYING(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    supervision CHARACTER VARYING(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    estado CHARACTER VARYING(1) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    usuarioregistrosistema CHARACTER VARYING(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    fecharegistrosistema TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_p_proyecto PRIMARY KEY (id_proyecto),
    CONSTRAINT fk_p_financiamiento_p_financiamiento FOREIGN KEY (id_financiamiento)
        REFERENCES public.p_financiamiento (id_financiamiento) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_p_municipio_p_municipio FOREIGN KEY (id_municipio)
        REFERENCES public.p_municipio (id_municipio) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

El problema esta cuando quiero hacer un insert omitiendo el campo id_proyecto que debería ser adicionado de forma automática.
Pero me sale este error:

```
ERROR:  relation "p_proyecto_id_proyecto_seq" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

Tanto en el pgadmin como en el PHP tengo el mismo error.
Hice algo mal al asignar el valor **autoincrementable**?

Answer (score 2):

Si declaras el primer campo como SERIAL, digamos algo como

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    nombre text
);
```

Por debajo se creará una secuencia cuyo nombre se deduce del nombre de la tabla, y se asigna el valor DEFAULT para dicha columna. Si inspeccionas la tabla recién creada verás que su definición es

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tú estás haciendo es bautizar la secuencia arbitrariamente, y PostgreSQL no hará ninguna creación automágica por debajo.

Answer (score 0):

El error simplemente quiere decir de que no encuentra el sequence `p_proyecto_id_proyecto_seq`. Si no lo has hecho ya, es necesario que creas el sequence de antemano:

```
create sequence p_proyecto_id_proyecto_seq
```

También, aunque técnicamente la sintaxis del `nextval` que usas no es incorrecta, no es la ideal. La sintaxis que usas es una antigua que no verifica la existencia del sequence hasta que trate de insertar un registro. Es mucho mejor que la verificación se haga de una vez con el `create table ...`.

Para esto, simplemente necesitas expresarlo de la siguiente manera, sin los casts adicionales:

```
CREATE TABLE public.p_proyecto
(
    id_proyecto INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('p_proyecto_id_proyecto_seq'),
...
```

Tal vez lo intentastes de esta manera antes y te dio el error que mencionas, y lograstes eliminar el error con los casts. Pero en realidad, lo único que hicistes es posponer el momento donde te aperece el error. Al final, de una forma u otra, debes asegurarte que el sequence exista.